# escaped xml inside xml element

Tags: xml, deserialization

I have xml what il get from third party application and structure looks like this:

```
<root>
 <id>1</id>
 <data>&lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;\n\r
  &lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;</data>
</root>
```

As u can see there is a escaped xml inside `<data>`, also in the end of first line of `<data>` there is a newline `\n\r` and 2 spaces in front on the 2 line in `<data>`.

Here is my deserialize method:

```
public static root Deserialize(string xml)
{
    System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
    try
    {
        stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
        return ((root)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
    }
    finally
    {
        if ((stringReader != null))
        {
            stringReader.Dispose();
        }
    }
 }
```

Afther using this method the value of data element is:

```
"&lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;\n  &lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;"
```

And now, my questions are:

Why is the `\r` removed from the data string?
Is there a way to remove the newlines and spaces some other way than using simple `string.replace();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the value of data element is:
>
> ```
> "&lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;\n  &lt;node&gt;i like it&lt;node&gt;"
> ```

No, the value actually is

```
"<node>i like it<node>\n  <node>i like it<node>"
```

> Why is the `\r` removed from the data string?

The `\r` is normalized. Line-breaks in XML are `\n`-only, any occurrence of different types of line-breaks is being replaced as part of the XML parsing process.

> Is there a way to remove the newlines and spaces some other way than using simple `string.replace();`?

You *could* regex-replace `\n$\s*` with the empty string:

```
Regex.Replace(data, @"\n\s*", String.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline)
```